# How to return data i got from database, from model back to controller

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Nodejs and cloud firestore as a database, i got the right data from database (logout) in model but after returning it back to controller i can not got it

```
// this is controller:

CheckPhoneNumber = (req, res) => {

    // getting data from json

    var json = {

        // this is the entry ==> PhoneNumber : 123456789

        PhoneNumber: req.body.PhoneNumber
    }

    // calling model function

    console.log('this is from controller before calling database');

    var user = model.CheckPhoneNumber(json.PhoneNumber)
        .then(function () {
            console.log('this is from controller after calling database');
            console.log(user);
            return user;
        }).catch(err => {
            return 'Error in controller awaiting ', err;
        });

    // outputting to Postman 

    return res.json(Promise.resolve(user));
}
```

and that controller calls the below model

```
// this is model :

// importing configure of database 

const config = require('../config/main');

// this is for updates from google to firestore

config.db.settings({ timestampsInSnapshots: true });

// setting root of users database 

const usersRoot = config.db.collection( my root here );


// takes json and return that user which phone number belongs to (actually it gets user by phone number )



async function CheckPhoneNumber(PhoneNumber) {
    // getting data from database
    var user;
    user = await usersRoot.where('PhoneNumber', '==', PhoneNumber).get()
        .then(async snapshot => {
            if (snapshot.empty) {
                return 'No matching documents.';
            }
            return await snapshot.forEach(async doc => {
                console.log('your user is : ');
                user = await doc.data();
                console.log(user);
                console.log('this is from model after calling database');
                return await user;
            });
        }).catch(err => {
            // console.log('Error getting documents',err);
            return 'Error getting documents', err;
        });
    console.log('this is user befor returning : ');
    console.log(user);
    return user;
}
```

and this is the output of console in windows OS

```
this is from controller before calling database

this is from model after calling database

{ ... there is here some data ... }

this is from controller after calling database

Promise { <'pending'> }
```

I expect to get the data i returned from controller speicially after i await it to get data from database in the last line of console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your `user` is a `promise` object.

You may want to respond in this block like,

```
model.CheckPhoneNumber(json.PhoneNumber)
  .then(function (user) {
    console.log('this is from controller after calling database');
    console.log(user);
    res.json(user)
  })
  .catch(err => {
    res.json('error')
  });
```

Or, you do it this way:

```
// make you route function async
CheckPhoneNumber = async (req, res) => {
...

// then you could
try {
  const user = await model.CheckPhoneNumber(json.PhoneNumber)
  res.json(user)
} catch (e) {
  res.json('error')
}
```

change your model to:

```
async function CheckPhoneNumber(PhoneNumber) {
  // getting data from database
  try {
    var snapshot = await usersRoot.where('PhoneNumber', '==', PhoneNumber).get()
    if (snapshot.empty)
      return "No"
    var datas = [];
    snapshot.forEach(doc => {
      datas.push(doc.data())
    })
    return datas;
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
}
```

Comment: I still goting undefined user in these two ways

Comment: does this `console.log(doc.data());` print out the data? also what is the result of `console.log(snapshot)`

Comment: what is the result of `console.log(doc)`

Comment: the result of

 ```NodeJs

console.log(doc) 

 ```

is 

```console

 QueryDocumentSnapshot{ also too long data }
```

Comment: result of     ```NodeJs 

console.log(snapshot) ```
  is

```NodeJs 

 QuerySnapshot { _query: too long data } ```

Comment: try changing to `if else` in your `CheckPhoneNumber`

Comment: again undefined

Comment: what is the result of console.log(doc.date) if you query all docs `usersRoot.get()`

Comment: console.log( doc.date()) is the data it self

Comment: opps not date i mean  doc.data(), sorry

Comment: yeah console.log( doc.date()) is the data that's in database

Comment: I believe, the issue with your firestore query, double check and get the data atleast first from firestore and then work your way up. If you're having difficulty fetching data from firestore, you might want to ask new question on that

Comment: i got my data from Firestore correctly, but in .then() at model i can log it but out parentheses of .then() i got undefined

Comment: can you link your entire code to some codepen, jsfiddle or something?

Comment: how to link ? and also i updated model file you can check it again

Comment: what i am saying is that in model inside .then() i got my data correctly,but when returning the value is undefined